# How to display date using PCMAC.INC

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

I am trying to make a program that displays the date (month, day, year). The month and day are displayed correctly, but the year is messed up. Note, the register dh = month, dl = day, and cx = year. Here is my code:

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC
  .MODEL SMALL
  .586
  .STACK 100h

  .DATA
Message DB 'Today is $'
Slash DB '/'
Month DW ?
Day DW ?
Year DW ?

  .CODE
  EXTRN PutDec : NEAR
Hello PROC
  _Begin
  _GetDate

  mov al, dh
  mov ah, 0
  call PutDec

  mov al, dl
  mov ah, 0
  call PutDec

  mov ax, cx
  mov ah, 0
  call PutDec

  _Exit 0;
Hello ENDP
  END Hello;
```

Comment: You realize you set CX to AX and then immediately overwrite AH?

Comment: Oh derp, thanks solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC
  .MODEL SMALL
  .586
  .STACK 100h

  .DATA
Message DB 'Today is $'
Month DB ?
Day DB ?
Year DW ?

  .CODE
  EXTRN PutDec : NEAR
Hello PROC
  _Begin
  _GetDate

  mov al, dh
  mov ah, 0
  mov Month, al
  ;call PutDec

  mov al, dl
  mov ah, 0
  mov Day, al
  ;call PutDec

  mov ax, cx
  mov Year, ax
  ;call PutDec

  mov al, Month
  mov ah, 0
  call PutDec
  _PutCh '/'

  mov al, Day
  mov ah, 0
  call PutDec
  _PutCh '/'

  mov ax, Year
  call PutDec

  _Exit 0;
Hello ENDP
  END Hello;
```

Comment: Why not just write `mov ax,cx` ? No need to fill in the *Year* variable, you don't fill in the *Month* and *Day* variables neither.

Comment: In order to put slashes, you have to call _PutCh, which clears the dl register . So I am using the day variable to save the date before it is erased.

Comment: You can set the variables straight from DH, DL, and CX. No need to first assign to AL/AX.